# How to compile my project to java 1.5 if the library I use has source and target level of 1.7?

Tags: java, maven, compilation, spark-java

I'm working on a web application which needs to be run on a legacy WebSphere server which runs on an 1.5 JVM.

My problem is that if I set the source/target level to 1.5 in my pom file it works fine

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

until I add a dependency to my project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked its pom file and it has 1.7 as source/target:

```xml
<configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <optimize>true</optimize>
        <debug>true</debug>
</configuration>
```

I get this error when I try to start up my app:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
```

If I set the target level in my project maven fails with another error:

```
[ERROR] javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Which IDE you are using?

Comment: Then you **can't** compile it to 1.5. You have a dependency that requires 1.7

Comment: 1. Don't use that dependency in this particular project or 2. upgrade Java so it matches the requirements of this project

Comment: I wouldn't be asking this question if any of those were an option.

Comment: IMO, they are the only correct options. Something has to give, it will probably require some effort. That's not a problem unless you make it a problem.

Comment: I don't make it a problem others do. I would never choose 1.5 as target myself. The decision was made elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using maven, and that means the `spark-core` dependency is being pulled from maven central as compiled bytecode in a .jar file.

The [pom for that project on github](https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/pom.xml) has it being compiled to Java 7 bytecode. I'm willing to bet money that's what is uploaded to maven central.

The only way it would be possible for you to target Java 5 and use that library would be to clone the project, modify its pom to specify 1.5, and build your own jar.

That said, it is highly unlikely that it will build for a ten year old version of Java given that they specify 1.7 in the pom; they are probably using Java 1.7 features.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the code, compile it as 1.5 (if it compiles) and insert into your own repository.

Comment: I highly suspect a dependency whose pom says it requires java 1.7 is not going to compile to a 10 year old version of Java.